Can Windows firewall WF.msc do TCP port forwarding at all, like Linux iptables does?
Client machines can reach TCP 25 on "gateway" server (we control this segment and all firewalls there). This "gateway" server can reach SMTP relay out there somewhere (we don't control that path).
We don't want to maintain SMTP relay on the "gateway" server, instead, just forward TCP 25 through it. More ports to come later. UDP too.
Temporary solution would be with netsh, but even that doesn't work:
On the "gateway":
telnet a.b.c.d 25 - this works, I get SMTP hello and can create email from telnet prompt.
Started wf.msc on this gateway, made a new standard inbound rule for tcp 25, accept all remote addresses on all NICs. This is topmost allow rule, so I presume nothing is blocking inbound TCP 25 on the gateway server.
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=25 connectport=25 connectaddress=a.b.c.d (where a.b.c.d is the IP of the remote SMTP server)
netsh interface portproxy show all - looks good, proxy is enabled for all interfaces
netstat -an - shows LISTENING on TCP 25
telnet 127.0.0.1 25 - connection failed.
Hmm.. what is "failed", anyway? What does it mean? Is it TCP NAK, i.e. "refused". or something else?
This netsh thing was just an intermediate test, anyway.
Preferred long-term solution would be port forwarding with a permanent rule in Defender on the gateway host, created with WF.msc
Here's what I tried for that:
Removed that "standard" inbound allow rule for TCP 25 mentioned before, and instead, tried to create the "custom" input rule.
Confusing is what WF.msc means by "remote addresse(s)" and even ranges field there.
How can one forward a TCP session to many addresses or even ranges?
I suspect it still means source IPs for incoming connections.
But then, where else can I specify the destination IP to forward to?
Or am I looking at the wrong solution?
Please don't suggest 3rd party apps, we are strictly bundled to MS tools & features.

Why can't you just use proper routing? The Windows firewall does not forward anything, it permits or denies traffic, in, out and across. How can one forward a TCP session to many addresses or even ranges? - that isn't possible. Product recommendations are off topic, like on nearly all SE sites. Try [softwarerecs.se].

that's is not entirely true, Windows can forward the traffic via netsh, as also it can nat via powershell in example

Like I said, we can't use "proper routing", because we don't control the firewall/router above our gateway, which passes/routes upstream only the gateway's IP to SMTP server. We can't add neither routing nor FW rules to that upstream router/FW, hence port forwarding or NAT masquerading ou our gateway are our only options. What did you mean by NAT? Cat windows do full NAT/Masquerading, aggregating all IPs coming to the gateway, into single IP going out? How?

Can Windows Firewall forward the traffic?

nope

can netsh forward the traffic?

maybe, not the best solution but a workaround.

Syntax
add v4tov4 listenport= {Integer | ServiceName} [[connectaddress=] {IPv4Address | HostName}] [[connectport=] {Integer | ServiceName}] [[listenaddress=] {IPv4Address | HostName}] [[protocol=]tcp]

An Example
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 listenport=25 connectaddress=192.168.0.20 connectport=25

i used 192.168.0.20 for the address that should be contacted and port 25 as requested
Reference:
Microsoft

Thank you for a honest answer. I am still in doubt though - if Windows can do IP port forwarding with netsh, why can't it do the same with a persistent firewall rule? The mechanics must be the same I guess.


Confusing is what WF.msc means by "remote addresse(s)" and even ranges field there.
How can one forward a TCP session to many addresses or even ranges?

What it means is that you're creating a filter rule – not a "port forward" rule. Windows Firewall (wf.msc) is a filtering facility first and foremost; the fields you see are meant to match the existing fields in IP packets (source IP and destination IP, depending on direction) and have nothing to do with "port forwarding" i.e. rewriting with new values.
(The term "port forwarding" is a bit unfortunate; DNAT is something that happens before the forward decision, and it's not the firewall that forwards packets...)
So yes, "remote address(es)" can be a range because it represents the possible client addresses – source IP addresses – that this rule is intended to allow.
The XP/2003 firewall was technically part of the Internet Connection Sharing service, so it had "port forwarding" built-in because ICS already had it first (ICS was made to mimic a home gateway in all aspects), but the same doesn't apply to the new AdvFw. I think the "Windows Filtering Platform" can do NAT internally but it's just not exposed through wf.msc at all.
What you can probably do on modern systems is use New-NetNat and Add-NetNatStaticMapping from PowerShell; I believe that's what WSL/Hyper-V uses for its outbound NAT, but it seems that it is now available without installing the Hyper-V feature.

if Windows can do IP port forwarding with netsh, why can't it do the same with a persistent firewall rule? The mechanics must be the same I guess.

They are not. Netsh portproxy is not "port forwarding" in the sense routers handle it – it is literally a proxy, where Windows itself accepts the TCP connection on one side and initiates a second TCP connection on the other side (basically like HAProxy or Nginx). This is completely different from the per-packet rewriting that firewalls do to implement DNAT.

as said it is a workaround instead of a solution. But even a workaround is a way of solving if we see it like ITIL. however I agree that the nat would also work. Due i wrote the answers on my mobile phone, I restricted myself to one solution ;)
